# Изменить цвет текста JS

Tags: php, javascript

Всем привет!
Необходимо изменить цвет текста.

Есть некий цикл который выводит список разделов на сайте

```
<div class="main-menu">
    <a href="/catalog/">
        <?=$arResult['NAME']?>
    </a>
</div>
```

Нужно поменять цвет текста в зависимости от того, какой раздел выводится.
Например есть разделы:
Одежда
Обувь
Куртки
Велосипеды

Нужно, что бы разделы "Обувь" и "Велосипеды" были красным цветом.
Реализовать нужно с помощью JS
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, это bitrix.
Лучший способ для тебя будет создать пользовательское поле у раздела из админки, назвать его "цвет текста", со строчным типом. В него засовывать значения типа `#ff0000` или вообще просто `red`. Выводить так:

```
<div class="main-menu">
    <a href="/catalog/" style="color: <?=$arResult["UF_TEXT_COLOR"]?>;">
        <?=$arResult['NAME']?>
    </a>
</div>
```

где `UF_TEXT_COLOR` - код свойства, которое создашь.

Comment: Да, это битрикс. Но к сожалению такой метод в моем случае не подходит, долго объяснять, просто поверьте=) Проще через js, только у меня с ним туго, надеюсь тут помогут.